# Python: Convert ctypes_ubyte array to String

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I have a ctype Structure and I want to print a byte array which I know is string. How do I convert this ctypes.c_byte array into string?

```
from ctypes import *

class File(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("fileSize", c_uint),
        ("fileName", c_byte * 32)]

f = File()
print(f.fileSize)
print(f.fileName)
```

Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you'd have to know how the byte is encoded, UTF-8?

Comment: @figs Yes it is UTF-8.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `c_char * 32` instead. This automatically creates a Python string.

Answer (score 4):

If the empty indexes of your byte array are zeroed out you can do this:

```
print(''.join([chr(i) for i in f.fileName]).rstrip('\x00'))
```

Alternatively you could use `ctypes.c_char_p` instead of a `ctypes.c_byte*32` to have an already printable string in your structure. It's also possible to cast the `c_byte` array to a `c_char_p` via `ctypes.cast` e.g.

```
filename = ctypes.cast(f.fileName, ctypes.c_char_p)
print(filename.value)
```

Comment: Alternative to casting (simpler; no FFI call): `c_char_p(addressof(f.fileName)).value`. Alternative to the list comprehension using an array: `(c_char * len(f.fileName)).from_buffer(f.fileName).value`.